# Error detection in AS400

Tags: vba, ibm-midrange

I now basics of VBA and use it to send or get data in AS 400, but I am not so advanced to understand documentation of IBM "Host Access Class Library". I want to know how can I detect error in AS400 for now I am using script below or skip errors by self, outside of running macro.

[image: AS400 error]

```
Sub check_error()
    autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable
    autECLSession.autECLPS.wait 100
    autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[reset]"  
End Sub
```

When error appear I cannot use some commands like autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady, So instead I use 'wait 100' in my 'check_error' but it not always work. So how can I detect error, is there any command to do that? Or a method to handle it?

Comment: It's not clear whether your code make use of VBA's typical error handling code (On Error Goto Label, On Error Resume,...)  If not, here's a place to start: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/

Comment: I need returt value for detection error in AS400, if error come or not example: [If error then; x; else; y;end if;] not compilation error in vba language

Comment: VBA's error handling supplies return values to describe errors when you use Err.Number  & Err.Description, etc.  Have you tried using those? Also, be sure to supply some of your code in your question so those here can help you.  Thanks

Comment: Take a look at autECLOIA.NotifyOIAError

Answer (score 2):

This is a massive topic that, unfortunately, depends on the application. There are so many ways that errors can be presented to the user on a 5250 display that one method can not fit all circumstances. It might be best to just ask us about your specific use case rather than all use cases.

However, let me give you a high level view of some of the ways errors can be presented.

**External Message Queue**
This is when the program sends a status message to the *EXT message Queue. These messages are displayed on the last line of the display. They do not appear in the job log, and are typically not used for exceptions, but they also do not end the program.

**Program Message Queue**
An application can define a message subfile which is a record format that displays on the screen between lines 1 and 24 on an 80x24 screen, or between lines 1 and 27 on a 132x27 screen. Where it appears, and the number of display lines it uses are defined in the display file DDS. The appearance of a message in this message subfile may be the only indication of an error, but it may contain informational messages as well. You are going to have to determine which it is by the text of the message. In conjunction with the message, a field may also be reverse imaged, or colored in a way that indicates an error, but the keyboard is not locked, and there is no audible indication that there is a problem.

**DDS Error Messages**
DDS error messages can be defined that lock the keyboard, reverse image the field, and display an error message. These messages can be displayed on any line as well, which is configurable in the DDS. In addition to the typical display lines, there is an addition line: 25 on a 80x24 screen, and 28 on a 132x27 screen, that is accessible to these messages.

**Custom Error Messages**
And sometimes an error is indicated in a completely custom way, for example by populating a text field somewhere on the screen.

The point is that you need to know your application, and how it provides user feedback, and without that knowledge, we can't help you.

Comment: Have to give you credit for a valiant attempt in the face of an underspecified question.